# How recover sybase database (unknown db version)

Tags: sqlanywhere, data-recovery

I have a database file (*.db) that need to be recovered.

The bad is, the end-user have null idea of the version of the database. Not know the password. The original developer is lost. The computer where was installed was formatted. We have not experience in this database software. Yeah, nightmare.

My *guess* is a old database. I'm trying to open it in Sybase 11, dev edition.

I follow this steps: http://dcx.sybase.com/1101en/sachanges_en11/unloading-reloading-upgrading-newjasper.html

I try to use the UNLOAD utility from command line & from the Sybase central utility. From command line I do:

```
./dbinfo -c "DBF=/Users/mamcx/Downloads/CEMDE_ENDOCRINO_S.A.DB;UID=DBA;PWD=sql" 
SQL Anywhere Information Utility Version 11.0.1.2045
Unable to start specified database: '/Users/mamcx/Downloads/CEMDE_ENDOCRINO_S.A.DB' was created by a different version of the software
```

Ok, I try to unload:

```
./dbunload -c "DBF=/Users/mamcx/Downloads/CEMDE_ENDOCRINO_S.A.DB;UID=DBA;PWD=sql" -n /Users/mamcx/Desktop/
SQL Anywhere Unload Utility Version 11.0.1.2045
Connecting and initializing
***** SQL error: Unable to start database server
```

Ok, from the server admin tool:

```
dbunload -v -c "UID=dba;PWD=***;DBF=/Users/mamcx/Downloads/CEMDE_ENDOCRINO_S.A.DB" -an "/Users/mamcx/Desktop/baba.db" -ap 4096 -ea None -ii -sa -so _sc866192545
Connecting and initializing
***** SQL error: Unable to start database server
An error occurred while attempting to unload the database '/Users/mamcx/Downloads/CEMDE_ENDOCRINO_S.A.DB'.
```

Exist a way to know the version of the database server used to create this? Is possible to recover this file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get the version out of the Database File if you are not able to start it.

You could get a hint from the hopefully existing Client PC's. Check the ODBC Driver Version they have installed.

I had good success with the support of Sybase. If you or your client has a support contract you can get them involved.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try to simply start a server with that database and capture the output with `-z -o server.out`. The server.out file should contain a more specific error telling you why it can't start the database. This error can occur if you are trying to start something that is not a SQL Anywhere database.

You may also want to post this question over at http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/.